# How to soft delete functionality in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, soft-delete, neo4jphp, neo4j-node

In relational databases like mysql I was used to do soft delete by setting **deleted_at**.  And then for retrieving **SELECT just get rows WHERE deleted_at IS NULL**.

I am confused how to implement soft delete in neo4j database. There are multiple ways I am getting but not sure which method or combination will have more advantages.

I also read [Neo4j: implementing soft delete with optional relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606084/neo4j-implementing-soft-delete-with-optional-relationships) but not helping.

1. Just set property of node **deleted_at**.
2. Remove node label and change by prefix "_" like "Student" will become "_Student"
3. Remove relationship and change by prefix "_" like "TEACHES" will become "_TEACHES"

Which will be best way or combination or other way to achieve soft delete in neo4j?

Comment: *Which will be best way* - sounds like it's going to be app-specific. Since there's no direct support for soft-delete, I think this is really an opinion/subjective type of question. Neo4j has a `where` clause allowing you to do the same type of filtering on a `deleted_at` property. There's also nothing stopping you from having an extra label representing soft-deleted nodes, allowing you to filter them out. You probably want to benchmark whichever method you choose (e.g. for the methods you suggested, how well do they perform under load?).

Comment: @DavidMakogon: Yeah. I wanted to know anybody using soft delete. Then which way they are doing? I am new to neo4j. In my case, nodes that will be getting deleted have relationships mostly. If anyone have benchmarks, that will be greate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think have a `deleted_at` property for node. In which you can store deleted time-stamp.

And at the time of fetching nodes information you can check `deleted_at IS NULL`.
like -

```
  MATCH (n:node)
  WHERE n.deleted_at IS NULL
  RETURN n;
```

Storing time-stamp you can get when node is deleted.

You can also have relationship `deleted_by` between user who deleted the node. So that you can find out who deleted node.

Answer (score 4):

Which way is the best way will be debatable.  If you don't need the actual date of soft delete, then you can just apply/remove a label as necessary:

Mark as "soft deleted":

```
match (a {name: "foo"}) set a:deleted return a;
```

Unmark:

```
match (a {name: "foo"}) remove a:deleted return a;
```

If you need to assert properties about the soft delete, then it makes sense to model it as a node (e.g. a "soft deletion event") and then link it to the node via a relationship.  The nodes that are deleted then are any nodes of a certain type that have a "DELETED" relationship that goes to a soft-delete node.  That soft delete node would then have a deleted_at property, along with anything else about the deletion event you're modeling.

I don't think a simple `deleted_at` property in the node is as good of a solution, because it confuses the node information with the information about the deletion event.  I would argue you're trying to model a deletion event here.